# How to get Realm Objects by ID only?

Tags: swift, realm

I set up a Realm model (in Swift) with a children relationship:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MyObject1: RealmSwift.Object, RealmSwift.ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: RealmSwift.ObjectId
    @Persisted var childrenIDs = RealmSwift.List<String>()
}
```

I added the relationship as a `RealmSwift.List` of `String`s, because I intent to create other model classes, each with an ID, that can be added as children. In other words, the children might not be of a single type/class. For example:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class MyObject2: RealmSwift.Object, RealmSwift.ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: RealmSwift.ObjectId
    @Persisted var title: String
}
```

Now at some point, I have to fetch all the children by their ID, for example to show them in a list. But I do not know how. I know the `realm.objects(Class.self).filter` but this expects a single class type. So my question is, how can I fetch objects from a Realm only by their ID (ie without their class/type)?

Comment: You can't. Realm needs to know in which collection it should look for that ID. If you want the nested children why not using an EmbeddedObject and just insert the objects in that List? Have a look here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/relationships/

Comment: @baronfac Good call - however, Lists are homogenous so you can't insert objects of two different types so that wouldn't work as is. However, it can be done via a third object to store the id and type or using AnyRealmValue objects.

Comment: Good catch Jay and thanks for the very informative answer you provided! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, ObjectId's are generic and have no correlation to the object *class* they are tied to. So you can't do exactly what you want.

But... there are options.

**TL;DR**

1. create another object with properties to hold the id and the object type, defined by an enum or
2. Use AnyRealmValue to store the objects themselves

Long answers:

**Long answer #1**

Create a class to store the id and type. Suppose we have a database that stores wine grape types; some are white and some are red but you want to store them all in the same list. Let me set up an example

```
enum GrapeTypesEnum: String, PersistableEnum {
    case white
    case red
}

class Grape: Object {
   @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: RealmSwift.ObjectId
   @Persisted var grape_name = ""
   @Persisted var grape_type: GrapeTypesEnum
}

class GrapeObjects: Object { //contains the grape id string & grape type
   @Persisted var child_id = ""
   @Persisted var child_type: GrapeTypesEnum
}
```

so then the model would be

```
class MyObject1: RealmSwift.Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: RealmSwift.ObjectId
    @Persisted var childGrapes = RealmSwift.List<GrapeObjects>()
}
```

You could then create a couple of grapes

```
let whiteGrape = Grape()
whiteGrape.name = "Chenin Blanc"
whiteGrape.grape_type = .white

let redGrape = Grape()
redGrape.name = "Cabernet Franc"
redGrape.grape_type = .red

let grape0 = GrapeObjects()
grape0.grape_id = whiteGrape._id.stringValue()
grape0.grape_type = whiteGrape.grape_type

let grape1 = GrapeObjects()
grape1.grape_id = redGrape._id.stringValue()
grape1.grape_type = redGrape.grape_type
```

then finally store those objects in your class. Those can then be sorted, filtered and you will know which ID goes with what type of object

```
let anObject = MyObject1()
anObject.childGrapes.append(objectsIn: [grape0, grape1])
```

**Long answer #2**

Another option is to not store the objectID string but store the actual objects by leveraging [AnyRealmValue](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/define-model/supported-types/#anyrealmvalue)

```
class MyClass: Object {
   @Persisted var myList = List<AnyRealmValue>()
}

let red = WhiteGrape()
let white = RedGrape()

let obj0: AnyRealmValue = .object(red) //both of these are objects, 
let obj1: AnyRealmValue = .object(white) //  even through they are different objects

let m = MyClass()
m.myGrapeList.append(obj0)
m.myGrapeList.append(obj1)
```

Then you can take action based on the the objects type

```
for grape in m.myGrapeList {
   if let white = grape.object(WhiteGrape.self) {
      print("is a white grape")
   } else if let red = grape.object(RedGrape.self) {
      print("is a red grape")
   }
}
```